# duplicate axes in a figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

Sorry for a somewhat simple question. I am trying to generate a figure which displays the same animation but in different subplots. I'm starting simple and primarily focusing on duplicating the plot first.

I was originally thinking of attaching the handle for the subplot to the other plots

```
afig = figure;
a1{1} = axes('Position',[.01,.2,.2,.2], 'color','none','Xlim',[-10,10],'Ylim',[-10,10]);
a1{2} = a1{1};
a1{2}.Position = [.3,.2,.2,.2];
a1{3} = a1{1};
a1{3}.Position = [.6,.2,.2,.2];

obj = patch('Parent',a1{1},'XData',[1,3,1],'YData',[1,1,3]);
```

[image]

But this just moves the existing plot around as opposed to duplicating it. (on account that I'm still referring to the same object even though it has different names)

I next thought of just recreating the same setup 3 times and then update the animation, looping through the three, but this feels inefficient and computationally intensive.

```
afig = figure;
a1{1} = axes('Position',[.01,.2,.2,.2], 'color','none','Xlim',[-10,10],'Ylim',[-10,10]);
a1{2} = axes('Position',[.3,.2,.2,.2], 'color','none','Xlim',[-10,10],'Ylim',[-10,10]);
a1{3} = axes('Position',[.6,.2,.2,.2], 'color','none','Xlim',[-10,10],'Ylim',[-10,10]);

obj{1} = patch('Parent',a1{1},'XData',[1,3,1],'YData',[1,1,3]);
obj{2} = patch('Parent',a1{2},'XData',[1,3,1],'YData',[1,1,3]);
obj{3} = patch('Parent',a1{3},'XData',[1,3,1],'YData',[1,1,3]);
```

[image]

Is there a way to call 1 subplot, update that 1 subplot but have it propagate to other subplots?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want to do at the end? Presumably, you will not want to end up with three exactly equivalent subplots, but there will be some differences. What will they be?

Comment: Actually I am trying to make 3 identical subplots as I want to display the same animation in 3 separate regions. I am using a projector with a throw range of 60cm and ideally I will have 3 subplots at 10cm, 30cm, and 50cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do in the end, how complex the animations are, and if you can prepare your plots in advance.

First, if there are only a few objects, you could use the [`linkprop`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html) function to link graphics objects' properties:

```
afig = figure;
a1{1} = axes('Position',[.01,.2,.2,.2], 'color','none','Xlim',[-10,10],'Ylim',[-10,10]);
obj = patch('Parent',a1{1},'XData',[1,3,1],'YData',[1,1,3]);

a1{2} = copyobj(a1{1}, afig);
a1{2}.Position = [.3,.2,.2,.2];

a1{3} = copyobj(a1{1}, afig);
a1{3}.Position = [.6,.2,.2,.2];


linked_objects = [ a1{1}.Children, a1{2}.Children,  a1{3}.Children];
property_names = {'XData', 'YData', 'ZData'};

hlink = linkprop(linked_objects, property_names);


for ii = 1:10
    obj.XData(1) = ii;
    drawnow
    pause(0.01)
end
```

Here, we first create the base plot, then we copy the `axes` (note that children objects get copied, too, but not callbacks and other properties, see [`copyboy`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html)). We then link properties we may want to change during the animation (note that you could also link the `axes`' view properties), and then change them in a loop.

Another approach would be to change the object's properties in a main `axes` in every loop iteration, and copy the main `axes`' children to the other `axes` afterwards. This approach may be more costly – as a lot of objects get copied and rendered – but on the other hand, individual properties do not have to be tracked. Here is an example:

```
afig = figure;

a1{1} = axes('Position',[.01,.2,.2,.2], 'color','none','Xlim',[-10,10],'Ylim',[-10,10]);
obj = patch('Parent',a1{1},'XData',[1,3,1],'YData',[1,1,3]);

a1{2} = copyobj(a1{1}, afig);
a1{2}.Position = [.3,.2,.2,.2];

a1{3} = copyobj(a1{1}, afig);
a1{3}.Position = [.6,.2,.2,.2];

for ii = 1:10

    obj.XData(1) = ii;

    delete(a1{2}.Children);
    delete(a1{3}.Children);
    copyobj(a1{1}.Children, a1{2});
    copyobj(a1{1}.Children, a1{3});

    drawnow
    pause(0.01)
end
```

Finally, it could be an option to use [`getframe`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to just capture the rendered image and display it in the copy `axes`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, quick question. when I use 'copyobj', the function creates a brand new axes which I then have to reposition. Is it possible to use 'copyobj' to copy objects into an existing axes? I have a figure with axes already created and I plan to populate the axes with objects before starting the animation. If I can copy to an existing axes then it would fit greatly in my current setup.

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf The second example shows exactly that: copying `Children`. You could just adapt it to copy the children before the loop and link properties as in first example